# ARP broadcast, is my understanding correct?

Tags: vpn, arp

Having studied more of the networking side of the Internet from the perspective of a front-end web developer, the concept of ARP is still causing me confusion - but I have made some progress with understanding the purpose and uses of ARP and related security consideration.

Recently, I've tried to resolve my lack of understating of ARP with a couple of questions. But, this is a less concerned question and more of a need to actually understand.

**Environment, for example:**

5 individual devices connected to the same router.

Let me list them as:

| IP | MAC |
| --- | --- |
| 192.168.1.66 | 32:33:34:35:36:37 |
| 192.168.1.67 | 42:43:44:45:46:47 **(this is me)** |
| 192:168.1.68 | 53:53:54:55:56:57 |
| 192.168.1.67 | 63:64:65:66:67:68 |
| 192.196:1:69 | 73:74:75:76:77:78 |
| 192:168:1:254 | 83:84:85:86:87:88 **(router)** |

Now, in this example, which is a rough reflection of the actual environment - if I run `arp -a` in Command Prompt, I get the following:

| Interface: | Physical Address | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 192.168.1.67 ---0x6 **(that's me)** |  |  |
| ― 192.168.1.66 | 32:33:34:35:36:37 | dynamic |
| ― 192.168.1.254 **(router)** | 83:84:85:86:87:88 | dynamic |
| ― 224.0.0.22 | etc. | etc. |

Now, I think I understand that my machine has made an ARP broadcast, and 192.168.1.66 has replied, hence the IP appearing dynamic.

**Q:** However - and this is the first question: why haven't all the other IP address (machines) replied when they are all actively connected (I'm thinking about the ARP logs we see in Wireshark where every machine is broadcast to, and each reply)? Why would only one IP reply to the ARP Broadcast?

Secondly... running `arp -a` with VPN connected leads to a second interface list.

For example, beneath the above, a second list will appear with many IPs, pointing to Content Delivery Networks, Google DNS, VPN IPs.

Interestingly, this list does not show Physical Address because, of course, because there are no physical addresses to return, since they are basically *remote resources*.

**For example:**

| Interface: | Physical Address | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10.5.0.2 --- 0x25 **(that's me)** |  |  |
| ― 0.0.0.0 | Empty | static |
| ― 3.45.67.89 |  | dynamic |
| ― 192.168.1.66 |  | dynamic |

But then, oddly... a 192.168.1.66 IP will appear in this 2nd interface following running `arp -a`.

Therefore, my guess is - the 2nd interface ARP lookup contains all/any dynamic IPs as shown the 1st above interface, even if the 192.168 IP is not a remote server/resource.

**Q:** Finally - would running `arp -a` with VPN connected result in a mirroring of the 1st interface in respect of 192.168.1 address? As such, would running `arp -a` broadcast to the local network as well to remote resources?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this kind of question would be better suited for the [Network Engineering SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I think this is on topic here.

Comment: I believe the machine is asking "who has IP address 192.168.1.66", so only the machine with that IP address replies "I do", and give its ARP address.  ie ARP is not being broadcast, and IP address is being broadcast and a machine is responding.   Once the response is heard, the sender adds it to the arp table.

Comment: Your second question about a VPN and ARP is unclear.  Most of the times a VPN uses a "tun" driver (or similar), and there is no ARP or MAC address associated with it.  If its a "tap" driver - which is a lot less common because of the overheads, then the TAP interface would have its own MAC address associated with it.

Comment: A guess from me: `192.168.1.66` appears in your "second" ARP table (which probably has no actual MAC address at all, because it's a tun / L3 VPN) because after you connected to your VPN, even traffics for `192.168.1.0/24` (i.e. your LAN IP subnet) get routed into the tunnel (i.e. assuming the VPN server has a route for the destinations, you'll be accessing hosts at some remote sites that has an IP from `192.168.1.0/24`).

Comment: @davidgo I believe it is better suited on the [Network Engineering SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com) site since that site is focused _exactly_ on questions like this while SuperUser is really more broad in scope. If it can be answered here? Fine. But I believe a healthier discussion and answer can be provided on the [Network Engineering SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: I had considered N&E SE, but felt that it was more suited for SU given the somewhat general question. But all responses help in my further understanding. I think these responses are enough and provide pointers for further study.

Comment: @Giacomo1968: In my experience, if you go to [Network Engineering SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) with this kind of question, you will get laughed out of [Network Engineering SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) because [Network Engineering SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) only deals with enterprise hardware and not home networks.